# Is there any method to call window.print() api when the file was write from server side

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I wanna my PDF file printed when it was written from the server-side,
But I can not get any clue.

```
const pdfXmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">\n<pdf>\n<body fontsize="18">\nHello World!\n</body>\n</pdf>';

const pdfFile = render.xmlToPdf({
   xmlString: pdfXmlStr,
});
scriptContext.response.writeFile({
            file: pdfFile,
            isInline: true,
        });
```

Any tips/ opinions would help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I had not expressed my situation correctly.
I just wanna use Suitelet Script to render one pdf file back to the client request And call Windows.print() API so that the user does not need to click the print button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a server side like user-event, schedule, or Map/Reduce Script then you can't display the report directly to the user you can send the report by email or store it in file cabinet.

You can use suitelet if you want to display the report directly to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by pulling the file in an iframe but this is fragile.

If the user is in front of the screen it's not a big deal to return the file (inline:false) and have them handle it the way they handle all other Netsuite print jobs.

If you are trying to batch out documents so someone can pick them up off a printer you can use something like printNode which would allow you to send a pdf to a network printer any where in your organization.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var pdfXmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">\n<pdf>\n<body fontsize="18">\nHello World!\n</body>\n</pdf>';
var pdfFile = render.xmlToPdf({
  xmlString: xml,
});
scriptContext.response.setContentType("PDF", "print-me.pdf");
scriptContext.response.write(pdfFile.getValue());
```